TimestampedGeoJson with marker showing heading
I want to animate a boat travelling on a route. At the moment I can show the route as a line and the boat as a circle using TimestampedGeoJson:
# circle with following line
features = [
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': coordinates_list,
        }, 
        'properties': {
            'popup': 'ship position',
            'times': times_list,
            'icon': 'circle',
            'iconstyle': {
                'fillColor': 'green',
                'fillOpacity': 0.6,
                'stroke': 'false',
                'radius': 13,
            },
            'style': {
                'color': 'green',
                'weight': 2,
                'opacity': 0.6
            },
            'id': 'man',
        },
    }
]

plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(
    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': features},
    period='PT30M',
    add_last_point=True,
    auto_play=False,
    loop=False,
    max_speed=1,
    loop_button=True,
    date_options='YYYY/MM/DD',
    time_slider_drag_update=True,
    duration='P1M',
).add_to(m)

This yields the following image:

I also want to show the heading of the ship, therefore the circle no longer satisfies. How can I keep the same functionality (marker followed by line, and a time slider) and at the same time showing a marker with heading?

The examples in the reference have what you are looking for, so I created dummy data and created the code for your issue. Create the points according to the time frame. Add that point to geojson. The icon to be used can be a local file or an icon found on the web. I got a free image from here and converted this image, which I saved locally, to be the icon. Lines are added to the map with PloyLine().
import folium
import folium.plugins
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import base64

coordinates_list = [[x,y] for y,x in zip(np.linspace(52.691750, 55.274781, 10),np.linspace(4.630338, 2.685758, 10))]
coordinates_list_yx = [[y,x] for y,x in zip(np.linspace(52.691750, 55.274781, 10), np.linspace(4.630338, 2.685758, 10))]

times_list = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in pd.date_range('2024-05-01','2024-05-10')]

points = []
for t,c in zip(times_list, coordinates_list):
    item = {'time': t, 'coordinates':c}
    points.append(item)

boat_path = coordinates_list_yx

icon_path = r"C:\Users\data\python\stackoverflow\cruise.png"
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open(icon_path, 'rb').read())
icon_img = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode())

features = [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": point["coordinates"],
        },
        "properties": {
            "time": point["time"],
            "id": "house",
            "icon": "marker",
            "iconstyle": {
                "iconUrl": icon_img,
                "iconSize": [20, 20],
            },
        },
    }
    for point in points
]

features.append(
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": coordinates_list
        },
        "properties": {
            "popup": "Current address",
            "times": times_list,
            "icon": "circle",
            "iconstyle": {
                "fillColor": "green",
                "fillOpacity": 0.6,
                "stroke": "false",
                "radius": 13,
            },
            "style": {"weight": 0},
            "id": "man",
        },
    }
)

m = folium.Map(
    location=[55.374781, 2.685758],
    tiles="openstreetmap",
    zoom_start=6,
)
folium.PolyLine(locations=boat_path, color="green", weight=2, tooltip="path").add_to(m)

folium.plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(
    {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features},
    period="P1D",
    add_last_point=True,
    auto_play=False,
    loop=False,
    max_speed=1,
    loop_button=True,
    date_options="YYYY/MM/DD",
    time_slider_drag_update=True,
    duration="P1D",
).add_to(m)


m



Thank you for your answer. However what I am looking for is setting the direction of the icon equal to the heading of the ship. This is possible with boatMarker (https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/user_guide/plugins/boat_marker.html), but I cannot combine boatMarker with TimestampedGeoJson. At the moment I am using a circle, but a circle does not have a direction.  It does not necessarily need to be a boat shape, but something that has a direction that can be set.

If the trajectory is a straight line, there will be no problem if the image of the bow of the boat is oriented in that direction. However, if the boat's trajectory is not a straight line, it will be necessary to prepare an image that matches the direction of the trajectory.

In your answer you first draw the trajectory and then the ship moves over that line. I would like to follow the trajectory to the present position of the ship. Is that possible?

Moreover two boats are shown, the last and the second-last. Is it possible to show only the last one?

First, I do not know if it is possible to draw sequential lines. I don't know if it can be done if you have a line string of points, start points and end points from the data structure. Also, there are two ship loci, which means that there will be multiple examples of references. I thought the setting to control this was add_last_point, so I set it to false, but it had no effect.
